# JSF dropdown list inside a tab header

Tags: jsf, drop-down-menu, jsf-2, richfaces, tabpanel

I'm using JSF and rich faces 4.5.5 and I'm trying to display a dropdown in the header of a tab panel. So far this is what I have:

```
<rich:tabPanel id="reportTabPanel" >
    <a4j:repeat var="reportCategory" value="${workBean.categories}">
        <rich:tab>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:panelGroup>                   
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{reportCategory.currentSelection}" style="background:none;border:none;width:15px">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{reportCategory.availableReports}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText  value="#{reportCategory.displayedTitle}" />                          
                </h:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>

            <div id="reportContent" name="content" >
                <h:outputText value="#{reportCategory.displayedContent}" escape="false" />
            </div>              
        </rich:tab>
    </a4j:repeat>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

It displays fine. I have the drop-down arrow displayed on the left and the tab's name on the right of each tab header. However the event handling is dodgy. When I click the dropdown, the list opens and closes as soon as I release the button (preventing me from making a selection in the list). In order to select anything from the dropdown list, I have to keep the mouse button pressed and release it outside of the header area so that the list does not close. Only then am I able to select my option in the dropdown zone.
I believe that the tab header is grabbing the release button event and using it to change tab if needed (which seems obvious).

What I would like is the dropdown to take priority over the tab header. Anyway of doing that? 
Alternatively, is there a way of opening the dropdown when it is hovered over?

I'm not a huge expert in JSF. I've tried looking at implementing a custom Renderer but my issue is more to do with events than visual so not sure that is the right way to go. Any suggestion? Pointers?

Thanks 
w.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `onclick="event.stopPropagation()"` to the `h:selectOneMenu`, that will prevent the click event reaching the tab.

(That said why do you need a select in the tab header? It's a navigation element.)

Comment: I also added an onclick event handler and forced a refresh of the content and header with an ajax call and it works a charm
<f:ajax event="change" render="CurrentDisplayedContent CurrentDisplayedTitle" />

Comment: And just to answer your question, a select in a tab is a way of selecting a document in a number of categories. 
Tabs represent categories or groups of documents and each select displays the documents in that group.
In my case, each tab is a particular type of document and the select is the document tanslated in a given language.
Im no Ux expert (and whish we had one on this project) but this is how the project owner wants it displayed!